# Create video with size based on image and place a video somewhere with an offset

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying out FFMPEG and I am unsure how hard it is to do what I want. I have some device frames and I want to play a video inside the frame. For example, this is a device frame:

[image]

Now I want to play a video within the screen of the iPhone. I already got the exact X and Y offset where the video must be placed to show it correctly. I have the following challenges to make it work, and I want to make sure FFMPEG can do it before I spend to much time reinventing the wheel:

- The output of the video must be as big as the PNG. This is already a
  confusing part for me. I have the width and height already available,
  but the things I saw is that FFMPEG will take over the input of the
  video as final size. The final output of the video should of course
  be the length of the input video.
- The background must be transparant (so no black background, I want to
  play the video on top of a website so it's nice if it's transparant and the corners are not black).
- The ability to place a video somewhere with a specified X and Y
  offset inside the device frame.
- Not sure if it's possible in the same command, but maybe the video
  needs to be resized to make it fit. I got the exact dimensions for
  the video.

The things I struggle most is point 1 where the output video must have a transparant background and where the device frame is placed in. Does anybody got tips?

Comment: An alternative is to just load the PNG on the website and position a `<video>` tag underneath (using CSS layers, see `z-index` tutorials). That would be best for a website. Or is there a condition that it needs to be done only with FFmpeg?